# Deleting values from raster layer using R

Tags: raster, r

I am looking for a way to delete values in my raster layer in R programming. Assume I have a raster layer with the following unique values:

> 0,1,2,3,4. minimum is 0 and maximum is 4.

How do I delete all values of 0 from my raster layer to remain with the following unique values?

> 1,2,3,4

Comment: One way is `x[x == 0] <- NA`

Comment: "Delete" isn't really the word used here. You can't "delete" values from a raster, you can only replace them with something else, because the raster has to be a complete rectangular grid of values.

Answer (score 2):

It will be relatively easy to change a cell value. Just use the missing value NA to replace the 0. Sometimes, a special number indicates missing value in a raster (such as -999 or any obvious value that will be outside the range of the normal dataset you are working with).
For illustration, the code below would change raster of value 0 to NA. The thing to remember is, rasters are just data in a table that has spatial information.

```
library(raster)

#creation of an empty raster with 100x100 pixel
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)

#randomly assign 0,1,2,3 or 4 
for (i in 1:100){

  for(j in 1:100){
    r[i,j] <- sample(0:4,1,T)
  }

}

#now replace all 0 with NA
r[r==0] <- NA
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I wish all answers followed your example.

Comment: Thank you for solution. I tried that before, but I ended up with cells with  NAs. 
For example:
value (1): count(100);value(2):count(400);value(3):count(157);value(4):count(721);value(NA):count(1345).

Do you know a way to remove NAs too so that I can just remain with values I want.
For example: 
value (1): count(100);value(2):count(400);value(3):count(157);value(4):count(721)

Comment: @PeterNgimbwa Raster data will always be a rectangular grid of values. Values that are ignored (e.g. along the edges or data gaps) need to be handled by assigning NoData (i.e. NA) or another value (e.g. 0).